# Request App_GlobalResources directory on Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net

Question what do you do for request in Application_Start global asax i want to replace my path to my App_GlobalResources directory but i tried using request and it didn't work am i missing an assembly reference is there another way of doing it.

Updated Code:

```
List<string> languages = new List<string>
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("App_GlobalResources"), "*.resx"))
{
    string resource = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    if (resource.Length > 9)
    {
        string filename = resource.Substring(resource.IndexOf(".") + 1, resource.Length - resource.IndexOf(".") - 1);
        RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(filename);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            llanguages.Add(filename);

         } // error here
    }
} 
HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("Cultures", languages.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> languages = new List<string>(); 
 foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Users\\KIRK\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\App_GlobalResources", "*.resx")) 
 {
 string resource = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);  
 if (resource.Length > 9)     {       
 string filename = resource.Substring(resource.IndexOf(".") + 1, resource.Length - resource.IndexOf(".") - 1);         
 RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(filename);        
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))     
 {             languages.Add(filename);  
                } 
 } 
 } 
 HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("Cultures", languages.ToArray());
```

Comment: yeah i just figured that out ToArray worked. Do you know how I can get the directory of App_GlobalResources without using Request.MapPath and no displaying the whole path like in my example